# How to un-hide local email folders in Evolution?

Tags: evolution

As part of configuring Evolution I removed the "local" account, because I don't want any emails to be stored on only one machine. Unfortunately Evolution still configured all my email accounts to store sent emails "On This Computer" (sic). How can I get to those emails? Edit → Accounts only shows the "real" email accounts now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit → Preferences → Mail Accounts shows the "On This Computer" account. Simply enable it, recover emails, scour other account defaults for references to "On This Computer/[something]" and fix them, then disable it again.